# CollectionView subview not showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I want to put [this ring progress view (CoocaPod)](https://github.com/maxkonovalov/MKRingProgressView) inside CollectionView Cells. One Progress View is in one cell. Somehow, the ring progress view is not showing... This is my code:

CollectionView Controller Class:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class myCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var cellColor = true
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return 19
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    

        cell.backgroundColor = cellColor ? UIColor.red : UIColor.blue
        cellColor = !cellColor
        
        return cell
    }

}
```

CollectionView Cell Class:

```
import UIKit
import MKRingProgressView

class myCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var ringView: UIView!
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let ringProgressView = RingProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        ringProgressView.startColor = .red
        ringProgressView.endColor = .magenta
        ringProgressView.ringWidth = 5
        ringProgressView.progress = 1.0
        ringView.addSubview(ringProgressView)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

I selected myCollectionViewCell Class for Cell and myCollectionViewController for the ViewController at Main.storyboard

Does anyone can help me?
Thank you!

Comment: [Someone told me to change UICollectionView.self to myCollectionViewCell.self where I register the cell, then deleted his comment]Thanks! But then it gives me a "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" at the last line of the cell class (        ringView.addSubview(ringProgressView)
)

Comment: Ring View is a UIView inside the Cell, which should contain the progress circle

Comment: Ah you are doing this straight in the storyboard, I don't think you need to register anything. Just make sure you set the reuse identifier to `Cell` in the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks! Looks good now after uncommenting the line

Answer (score 0):

Uncommented the register line. Works now